# Generate equidistant points in spiral

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code for generating points in a spiral:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


initial_radius = 0.01
n_turns = 4

final_radius = 0.1

b = (final_radius - initial_radius)/(2*np.pi*n_turns)

start_theta = np.pi/2
end_theta = 2*np.pi*n_turns


s = np.linspace(start_theta, end_theta, 300)
x = (initial_radius + b*s)*np.cos(s)
y = (initial_radius + b*s)*np.sin(s)

plt.scatter(x,y, label="spiral")
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

However, the points are not being generate with equal spacing along the spiral.

How can I change the sampling of `s` to make them equidistant?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to calculate the total length as a function of `s`, so `L(s)`. Then we can inverse this relationship through intepolation to find `s(L)`. We can use this to find `s` values that give equispaced points! For more info, you might want to google "arc-length parameterization".

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

initial_radius = 0.01
n_turns = 4
final_radius = 0.1

b = (final_radius - initial_radius)/(2*np.pi*n_turns)

start_theta = np.pi/2
end_theta = 2*np.pi*n_turns

s = np.linspace(start_theta, end_theta, 300)
x = (initial_radius + b*s)*np.cos(s)
y = (initial_radius + b*s)*np.sin(s)

# Calculate the arc length
L = np.cumsum(np.sqrt(np.gradient(x)**2 + np.gradient(y)**2))
Ls = np.linspace(0, L[-1], 300)

# Find s values for equally spaced arc lengths
new_s = np.interp(Ls, L, s)

# Calculate x and y for equally spaced arc lengths
x = (initial_radius + b*new_s)*np.cos(new_s)
y = (initial_radius + b*new_s)*np.sin(new_s)

plt.scatter(x,y, label="spiral")
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

The other option is to determine the arc-length parameterization through analytical methods.

[image]

Comment: Do you know an algorithm that does not resort no `np.gradient` or `np.interp`?

Comment: @R.Smith you can do Euler forward stepping, something [like this](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6UyjXqZc2AK). Here `np.sqrt(b**2 + R**2 + 2 * b * R * s + b**2 * s**2)` is dL/ds which is given by `dL/ds = sqrt(dx/ds^2+dy/ds^2)`. So this uses the analytical gradient.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is the first point in the correct place? starting at theta = pi/2?

Comment: @R.Smith it is not, sorry. You can just change `s=0` to `s=start_theta`